Electronic bilge pump switch
I want to build an electronic switching circuit for sailboat bilge pump.
My idea is a latching transistor circuit that work with 3 wires. 2 long (low level) that won’t activate the switch but will keep it latched if its active until the water level drop to below and disconnect them. A third wire high up at the maximum level allowed to activate the switch and start the pump, that now will run till the water level drop below the first 2 wires and break the latch.
Can any one help me figure out how I would make this work? It needs to be somewhat robust to be reliable. 12 V pump and about 5 A.

What are the level sensors? Just wires placed at different highs to measure the resistance between them?

I wouldn't do it with transistors. A relay will do this job rather nicely:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
With bilge empty, LOW and HIGH are open, A is at off (0V), the relay is off, and the pump is not running.
As the bilge fills up, LOW turns on. The relay is still off, sine there's 0V at A.
Eventually, HIGH turns on, there's 12V at A, and RLY1 gets turned on via LOW. Once the relay turns on, the its output drives point A through D1 and maintains/latches the relay in on state.
As the bilge empties, LOW will eventually turn off, the relay coil will lose power, and the relay will open.
D1 used so that the HIGH switch only powers the relay coil and not the pump. Current cannot flow from HIGH through D1 backwards towards the pump.
D2 is needed to protect the switch contacts from inductive kick-back as the relay coil turns off.
The fuse protects the relay, cabling and switches from overcurrent. It needs to be appropriately sized. 10A should work. The wires need to be AWG14.
The battery, fuse and power switch should all be in close proximity.

The high and low switches act like an analog Schmitt trigger.  Very clever.  Perhaps control over the high / low hysteresis might be handy if the boat has a tendency to roll side to side a lot as sailboats tend to do.

to run  relays i need to use float switches. that is exactly what im trying to avoid.    the conductivity of the water is not enough to reliably trigger a relay
